# Create Bootstrap carousel with dynamic content using PHP

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating a Wordpress site and am trying to utilise a Bootstrap 5 carousel that rotates between the most recent blog posts on the site. *(Dynamic content.)*

It works, but the posts are being brought in vertically stacked, rather than aligned in three columns. (See below.)

[image: blog-posts]

Is there a way to have the content be pulled in as it is but sit next to each other in three columns?
Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

```
                <div class="row justify-content-center">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide animatedParent animateOnce" data-bs-ride="carousel">
                            <div class="carousel-inner animated fadeIn pb-5">
                                <div class="carousel-inner">

                                    <?php
                                    $brandPosts = new WP_Query('cat=3&posts_per_page=9&orderby=date');

                                    if ($brandPosts->have_posts()) {

                                        $counter = 0;
                                        $firstLoop = true;

                                        while ($brandPosts->have_posts()) {
                                            $brandPosts->the_post();

                                            if (0 === $counter) {
                                                ?>
                                                <div class="row carousel-item <?php echo $firstLoop ? 'active' : ''; ?>">
                                                <?php
                                            }
                                            ?>
                                                    <div class="col-4">
                                                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                                            <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" class="img-fluid mb-2">
                                                        </a>
                                                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h3 class="mb-0"><?php the_title(); ?></h3></a>
                                                        <p><?php echo excerpt(16); ?></p>
                                                    </div>    
                                            <?php
                                            ++$counter;
                                            $firstLoop = false;

                                            if ($counter === 3) {
                                                $counter = 0;
                                                ?> </div> <?php
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }

                                    wp_reset_postdata();
                                    ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>    
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1- you must remove row class from into while loop near the carousel-item class
2- create a div after carousel-inner and set row class to it.
3- also to improve the code write your query as image.

good luck

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gCLD.jpg